# how to remove java map value(not key) in java?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I have a java map with this key and values:

`Xperia:[EM_A, EM_B, M-bus +, M-bus -, MB1, MB2, MB3, MB4, MB5, DOUT1, DOUT2, DOUT3, DOUT4, DOUT5, DOUT6, DOUT7, DOUT8]`

I've tried this way but it not works:

```
final Iterator<Entry<String, ArrayList<String>>> iter = termekConf.devNameType.entrySet().iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                  final Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry = iter.next();
                  if(entry.getValue().equals(torlendoValue)) {
                    iter.remove();                  
                  }
                }
```

how can I delete a value not a key?
i really don't know it because the myMap.remove(key) just removes the hole key with values and i don't want it.

thank you!

Comment: `value` associates with `key`.

Comment: I didn't understand by what you meant by removing the value. You can find the key, and then set its value to null. Or you can remove the key-value pair completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myMap.devNameType.get('Key').remove('Value');

HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listC = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listD = new ArrayList<String>();

listA.add("1");
listA.add("2");
listA.add("3");
listA.add("5");

mMap.put("A", listA);
mMap.put("B", listB);
mMap.put("C", listC);
mMap.put("D", listD);


myMap.get("A").remove("3");
```

it removes the '3' value from key 'A'.

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

> how can i delete a value not a key?

I'm not sure why you would want to do this but you can't, AFAIK.

**Possible solution**

What you could do is change this `value` to an empty `String` or a default `String` value. Then when you want to look for "`key`s without a `value`" you can iterate over as you are and search for the empty `String`/default `value`.

To modify the current `value`, you should be able to use [setValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue%28V%29). So something like

```
if(entry.getValue().equals(torlendoValue)) {
                entry.setValue("defaultString");
}
```

Comment: The method setValue(ArrayList<String>) in the type Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the key and keep the value persistence, because the implemented class for `Map<K,V>` interface doesn't allow a value without any references, in other word the size of both key and values should be same.

but you may set the key as `null`, first you need to utilize a Map which acceps null values and it's `HashMap<K,V>` (javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html))
Example:

```
Map<String,Object> dic=new HashMap<>();
//filling the map
  for(String sx:dic.keySet()){
    if(<<cound the victim>>){
      synchronized(dic){//HashMap is not synchronized!
         Object ox=dic.get(sx);
         dic.remove(sx);
         dic.put(null,ox);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT :** and for removing a value, so it's going to be same.

```
Map<String,Object> dic=new HashMap<>();
//filling the map
String[] keys=dic.keySet().toArray();int i=0;
  for(Object ox:dic.values()){
    if(<<cound the victim>>){
      synchronized(dic){//HashMap is not synchronized!
          String key=keys[i]
          dic.remove(key);
          dic.put(key,null);
      }
    }i++;
  }
}
```